# Difference between oz vehadar regular shas and the murchevet edition?

Tags: product-recommendation, talmud-gemara, jewish-books

What are the differences between Oz Vehadar regular shas and the murchevet edition? Also has anyone seen the handcrafted chosen has that's 4500 NIS? Is it very nice? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following additional features are included in the Murchevet edition. I admit I may be missing a few.

In no particular order:

1. Tosafos HaRosh. Some volumes also include Tosafos Rabbeinu Peretz and/or Tosafos Rid
2. Mevo'os HaTosafos (summaries of the *gemarros* that Tosafos bring)
3. Chiddushei HaBach
4. Sefer HaMikraos (a listing of all the verses quoted, with a very brief commentary)
5. Ein Mishpat HaMaleh (full listing of rulings from Rambam/Shulchan Aruch that come from the *gemarra*)
6. In the Kodshim *masechtos*, they include the Chofetz Chaim's Likkutei Halachos
7. Sefer HeAruch

Basically, anything you'd find in the big red *gemarros* they sell. Not sure about the hand crafted set you're referring to.